# Which Python library would allow me to display certain geometrical shapes based on a set of predefined simple rules

Tags: python, canvas, visualization

Here is a set of simple rules:
[image: rule set]

And here is the output once this set of rules has been applied:

[image: output once the rules has been applied]

Please recommend a simple python library or a simple way that would allow me to use python to calculate and visualize such computations.

Please provide a beginner programmer friendly (easily comprehensible) answer.

Comment: Please, check [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two for loops.
The outer loop goes through the lines, the inner loop goes from left to right.

Since I like the indexing I would use numpy arrays of desired dimension.

For plotting you could use imshow. It takes directly the numpy 2D Array.